# ERROR.. Unhandled exception during build. When running pipeline

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline

Trying to run a pipeline, my set up:

- GitHub
- Elastic Beanstalk with autoscaling and load balancer
- S3 Bucket for persistent static-files

After running the pipeline it fails to deploy all instances with the same version.
So from my logs I've found out that it fails when running the container_commands.

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: project.settings
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: project.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles":
    /html: statichtml
    /static-files: static-files
    /media: media-files




**container_commands:
   10_deploy_hook_permissions:
     command: |
       sudo find .platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
       sudo find /var/app/staging/.platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;**
```

Which it execute this:

```
#!/bin/sh

source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
python /var/app/current/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate
```

NOTE: The app deploys perfectly fine when I run "eb deploy", but when deployment is triggered from pipeline than it goes in to "Degraded" status where the instance is still running but apparently no all the instances are running the same version.

Error from health:

```
over all :  - Command failed on all instances.
            - Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version 
              "app-221124_115515680871" (deployment 418).

instance :  - Application deployment failed at 2022-11-24T11:32:55Z with exit status 1 
               and error: Engine execution has encountered an error.
            - Incorrect application version "code-pipeline-575- 
              3e3311a14d472807da9bcf9f73d5778e38c9c651" (deployment 420). Expected 
               version "app-221124_1680871" (deployment 418).



from commands-logs

2022-11-24 15:36:24,190 P17748 [INFO] Command 10_deploy_hook_permissions
2022-11-24 15:36:24,239 P17748 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2022-11-24 15:36:24,239 P17748 [INFO]   find: ‘.platform/’: No such file or directory
2022-11-24 15:36:24,239 P17748 [INFO]   find: ‘/var/app/staging/.platform/’: No such file or directory
2022-11-24 15:36:24,239 P17748 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2022-11-24 15:36:24,239 P17748 [ERROR] Exited with error code 1
```

Also tried with different config :

```
container_commands:
  01_makemigrations:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate --noinput"
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput"


But this time I get this wrror :

2022-11-25 08:56:46,187 P2294 [INFO] Command 01_makemigrations
2022-11-25 08:56:46,222 P2294 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2022-11-25 08:56:46,222 P2294 [INFO]    python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2022-11-25 08:56:46,222 P2294 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2022-11-25 08:56:46,222 P2294 [ERROR] Exited with error code 2
```

I've also set the variable globally in my Elastic Beanstalk Env. Properties

Not sure what to do anymore.
It is clear that it cannot find the file or run the commands

Answer (score 0):

So the commands now run when i enter the backend folder

```
container_commands:
   10_deploy_hook_permissions:
     command: |
       sudo find .platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
       sudo find /var/app/staging/backend/.platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
```

However everything looks fine pipeline and commands wise but the server is not running, I don't get any errors messages.